# Issues with BrowserMob Proxy and Selenium

Tags: java, maven, selenium, proxy, browsermob-proxy

I can't setup BrowserMob Proxy working in my Selenium project. Like [described in BrowserMob Proxy github page](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy#using-with-selenium) I imported it in my code:

```
public class DriverBase {
    public WebDriver driver;
public BrowserMobProxy proxy;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
    proxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
        proxy.start(0);

     Proxy sproxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(proxy);

        DesiredCapabilities caps=new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, sproxy);
 driver = new ChromeDriver(caps);
```

I excluded from browsermob-core the slf4j transitive dependency and added slf4j-jdk14, so that the server could start (originally it couldn't).

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>net.lightbody.bmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>browsermob-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0-beta0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I also added manually com.google.guava 19.0 because server is not starting  with the latest guava version.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

In my test class I only start the browser:

```
public class TrafficTest extends DriverBase{

 @Test
 public void testTraffic()    {    
    driver.navigate().to("http://liveexpert.ru");
}
```

The browser starts, but doesn't open the site or have access to the internet. The original browsermob-core maven setup couldn't even start the server or browser.
The current setup throws an error:

```
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.net.HostAndPort.getHost()Ljava/lang/String;
```

Here is the full log

```
    Nov 10, 2017 2:50:17 PM org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.DefaultHttpProxyServer start
    INFO: Starting proxy at address: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:0
    Nov 10, 2017 2:50:17 PM org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.DefaultHttpProxyServer doStart
    INFO: Proxy listening with TCP transport
    Nov 10, 2017 2:50:17 PM org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.DefaultHttpProxyServer doStart
    INFO: Proxy started at address: /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:45981
    Starting ChromeDriver 2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4) on port 10442
    Only local connections are allowed.
    Nov 10, 2017 2:50:18 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
    INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
    Nov 10, 2017 2:50:19 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
    INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
    Nov 10, 2017 2:50:19 PM org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ClientToProxyConnection exceptionCaught
    SEVERE: (AWAITING_INITIAL) [id: 0x62631078, L:/127.0.1.1:45981 - R:/127.0.0.1:33244]: Caught an exception on ClientToProxyConnection
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.net.HostAndPort.getHost()Ljava/lang/String;
```

Is there any workaround to setup the driver to access the internet?

Answer (score 2):

By now the solution is to use [guava **22.0**](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Release22).

The versions 18,19 of guava cause the problem:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.net.HostAndPort.getHost()
```

Why is [explained here](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy/issues/638).

The newest version of guava 23.x gets rid of the problem, but, in turn, invokes another problem:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.<init>(Ljava/util/concurrent/ExecutorService;)V from class org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any selenium-java jar (in mavenrepo) that dependes on Guava 22, version 3.5.0 should but it is not in the repos. So I downgraded to 3.4.0, this combination worked for me:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.lightbody.bmp</groupId>
  <artifactId>browsermob-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>21.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The only thing not mathing would be browsermob-core naturally depends on Guava 22 instead of 21, but for what I needed (log requests) seems to work